# How in xslt would I change a tag to an attribute if the tag has no attributes but has content

Tags: xml, xslt, rdf

Specifically the xslt I'm trying to modify is located here: http://www.gac-grid.de/project-products/Software/XML2RDF.html

and the xml I'd like to process is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BGSInformation Major="2" Minor="0" Revision="1">
<ListingType>OSR</ListingType>
</BGSInformation>
```

right now the xslt it treating the ListingType as an object and transforming it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<rdf:Description xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126#" rdf:about="">
  <BGSInformation xmlns="#">
     <rdf:Description xmlns="" rdf:about="#BGSInformation">
        <Major xmlns="#">2</Major>
        <Minor xmlns="#">0</Minor>
        <Revision xmlns="#">1</Revision>
        <!-- *** --->
        <ListingType xmlns="#">
           <rdf:Description xmlns="" rdf:about="#BGSInformation/ListingType">
              <rdf:value>OSR</rdf:value>
           </rdf:Description>
        </ListingType>
        <!-- *** --->
     </rdf:Description>
  </BGSInformation>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

What instead i'd like it to do is detect that ListingType Anywhere in the document has no attributes and no child nodes and only text and instead transform it like if it were an attribute of BGSInformation. i.e:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<rdf:Description xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126#" rdf:about="">
  <BGSInformation xmlns="#">
     <rdf:Description xmlns="" rdf:about="#BGSInformation">
        <ListingType xmlns="#">OSR</ListingType>
        <Major xmlns="#">2</Major>
        <Minor xmlns="#">0</Minor>
        <Revision xmlns="#">1</Revision>
     </rdf:Description>
  </BGSInformation>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: You're confusing tags with elements. Your ListingType element includes two tags: a start tag and an end tag.

Answer (score 1):

This should be as simple as changing the matching expression on one of the templates - change:

```
<xsl:template match="@*" name="attributes">
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="@*|*[not(@*|*)]" name="attributes">
```

This should cause the template to apply to elements that have no attributes or child elements, as well as to attribute nodes.  The meat of that template

```
<xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{$ns}">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:element>
```

can apply equally well to either.

Comment: I think this does not address the issue.. The problem is if an element is encountered with no attributes and no child elements it should only output a certain xml if that element doesn't exist ANYWHERE ELSE in the document with no attributes and no child elements.